# For each loop for menu links that affect other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to understand how to make this code into a loop so I wouldn't have to copy the part where `$('.popup-[insert nr]').click` every time in the future a new menu link is made for navigation.
This code is in the purpose of: Click a link, toggle or add a class of show to a hidden `div` and if any other link is clicked after that every shown div will be hidden.

```
var popContent = $('.popup-1-content');
var popContent2 = $('.popup-2-content');
var popContent3 = $('.popup-3-content');
var popContent4 = $('.popup-4-content');

var popupArray = [popContent, popContent2, popContent3, popContent4];

$('.popup-1').click(function () {

    if ( popContent.hasClass("show") ) {
        popContent.removeClass("show");
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < popupArray.length; i++) {
           popupArray[i].removeClass("show");
        }
        popContent.addClass("show");
    }
    return false;
});

$('.popup-2').click(function () {

    if (popContent2.hasClass("show") ) {
        popContent2.removeClass("show");
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < popupArray.length; i++) {
           popupArray[i].removeClass("show");
        }
        popContent2.addClass("show");
    }
    return false;
});


$('.close-popup a').click(function(){
$('.popup-content').toggleClass('hide').removeClass('show');
return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML too? What's the connection between `.popup-1` and `.popup-1-content`?

Comment: It seems i have written a too vague of a description. I have made a really fast fiddle and as you can see i am developing it from wordpress to create full screen popup content with each nav click . https://jsfiddle.net/bleedeagle/wrpsujug/ - i need the code to trigger divs further away from the nav not as a child elements

Comment: @KevinLehtla Update includes condensed jQuery (3 lines) and it no longer depends on location of links or popovers (as long as they are on the same page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab all the popups using a better CSS selector. Then iterate over the list using jquery's `each` attaching a click handler to each one.

You're toggling a class manually but JQuery has `toggleClass` built in. Use that instead. In your case you stated that you wanted to remove the class from all other elements once one popup had its class changed, to do that we can use jquery's `.not` method which specifies to get all items except the item specified, then we just use `removeClass` to remove the class from those elements.

```
var popups = $('[class$="-content"]').filter('[class^="popup-"]');

popups.each(function(index, popup) {
  $(".popup-" + (index + 1)).click(function(e) {
    $(popup).toggleClass("show");
    popups.not(popup).removeClass("show");
  });
});
```

```js
var popups = $('[class$="-content"]').filter('[class^="popup-"]');

popups.each(function(index, popup) {
  $(".popup-" + (index + 1)).click(function(e) {
    $(popup).toggleClass("show");
    popups.not(popup).removeClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.show {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="popup-1">toggle 1</button>
<button class="popup-2">toggle 2</button>
<button class="popup-3">toggle 3</button>
<button class="popup-4">toggle 4</button>

<div class="popup-1-content">1</div>
<div class="popup-2-content">2</div>
<div class="popup-3-content">3</div>
<div class="popup-4-content">4</div>
```

Comment: I think code works wonders but the only thing left is removing the toggle from other elements once new is toggeled. Any idea?

Comment: It seems that console logging out the code it is triggering classes like .p-content on my page rather than .popup-content.

Comment: @KevinLehtla I updated. So the reasoning behind your issue was the CSS Selector that I provided. Based on the code you provided I didn't know there were any other elements that also ended in "-content". I updated this to first get all the elements with a class that ends in "-content" and then filters all those to get the elements that _also_ have a class that begins with "popup-"

Comment: Hey thank you so much for helping but now only one issue needs to be addressed - once new link is clicked i need the other ones to have toggle removed. In my case all other popups would close if i click a new one. Once that's done this can be made into answer

Comment: @KevinLehtla Sure, so just to clarify because it makes a difference, do you think these pop up links are going to have any other click events attached to them, or just the one that you want removed?

Comment: @KevinLehtla sorry, I misunderstood. I updated the answer to do what you asked.

Comment: Amazing - works perfectly! Will mark this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your HTML structure is hard, but the idea is to create a loop for each link and replace the numbers with an index variable like this:

```
$.each('a', function(i, link) {
    $('.popup-' + i).click(function () {

        $('div').removeClass("show");
        $(this).parent.addClass("show");

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: While this has nice minimal code my solution needs the divs to be hidden at first and on click made visible. There is also problem as .popup-1 needs to target .popup-1-content not all .popup-content divs.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

> *"...i tried your code but it needs to be edited so it wouldn't target divs below the link as the divs are located in random parts of the page. "*

The updated demo addresses previously mentioned issue by adding a `data-*` attribute to each link. Once a link is clicked, it locates the nth `div.pop` by matching its `data-idx` with a `.pop`'s indexed position by using `.eq()` method. The following example does not function as is, it is merely the relevant parts with emphasis on the index number to show the correlation between the 2 values.

`<a href='#/' class='lnk' data-idx=`'**3**'`>POP3</a>`

`$('.pop').eq(`**3**`).addClass('show')`

The following is the core code without the extra utilities or comments, condensed and chained.

```
$('.lnk').on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).data('idx');
  $('.pop').removeClass('show').eq(idx).addClass('show');
});

 <a href='#/' class='.lnk' data-idx='0'>POP0</a>
```

For the complete updated code, refer to the Demo below.

---

On any automated or manually controlled groups of elements (ex. slider) that alternate in states (ex. hide and show), the easiest way to control the flow is to hide all elements and then show the currently active element.

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
/* This is just to space the links apart. Upadted to provide
|| random location for .lnk's
*/
$('a.lnk').each(function(idx, a) {
  var ran = getRandom(1, 60);
  a.style.top = (idx * ran) + 'px';
  a.style.left = (idx * ran) + 'px';
});

// Click any a.lnk...
$('a.lnk').on('click', function() {

  // Reference the div.pop the clicked link belongs to

  /* The next statement works if each popup was positioned after
  || a corresponding link. It is commented out in leiu of the 
  || uncommented statement that follows this statement.
  */ // var pop = $(this).next('div.pop');

  // Get the clicked link's data-idx number
  var idx = $(this).data('idx');

  // Gather all .pop
  var pop = $('.pop');

  // ALL .pop remove class .slow
  pop.removeClass('show');

  /* .pop will open. The specific .pop that corresponds with the
  || clicked link is determined by matching the .pop's current
  || indexed position with that of the indexed position of in     
  || $('.pop') by using the eq() method and passing data-idx
  */
  pop.eq(idx).addClass('show');

});

/* This function is not neccessary. Its purpose is to generate a
|| random number between min and max parameters (inclusive)
*/
function getRandom(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
a.lnk {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background:#000;
  color:gold;
  
}

.pop {
  display: none;
}

.pop.show {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px
}
```

```html
<a href='#/' class='lnk' data-idx='0'>POP0</a>
<a href='#/' class='lnk' data-idx='1'>POP1</a>
<a href='#/' class='lnk' data-idx='2'>POP2</a>
<a href='#/' class='lnk' data-idx='3'>POP3</a>
<a href='#/' class='lnk' data-idx='4'>POP4</a>


<div class='pop'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg'>
  <header>POP0</header>
</div>


<div class='pop'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg'>
  <header>POP1</header>
</div>


<div class='pop'>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg">
  <header>POP2</header>
</div>


<div class='pop'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg'>
  <header>POP3</header>
</div>


<div class='pop'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg'>
  <header>POP4</header>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - i tried your code but it needs to be edited so it wouldn't target divs below the link as the divs are located in random parts of the page. Think of it as triggering popup codes located in the footer via navigation

Comment: @KevinLehtla I had to venture a guess since OP was lacking HTML. See updated Demo, note the optional function that spaces the links is now modified to randomly place links . This is just for demonstration purposes to assert that the updated code does not rely on location within the DOM to function correctly.

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne but this is too confusing for my level of knowledge in js. I want to always understand what i am writing and why would i choose this path. Currently i got a very simple answer for my problem answered which is why i chose it

Comment: @KevinLehtla You sell yourself short, sir. I made it simpler than the other answers by avoiding iteration (i.e. `.each()`) . The only maintenance involved would be a number given to each link., all other HTML stays the same. I believe if the HTML was posted, it would be evident whether the `.popup-*` is a separate link or it's the popup itself? Anyways, it's more important that you found the most suitable solution. The fact that you gave each answer due consideration is how an OP should conduct oneself. Thank you and happy coding to you, sir. 

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class.

```
<!-- Added a common class popup-content -->
<div class=".popup-1-content popup-content">...<div>
```

select the common class when adding the event handlers, refer to `$(this)`, assuming you are using jQuery, to get the instance where the event occurs (specific element clicked) this can also be captured with event.target in vanilla js when passing it into your callback function handling the event.

ex jQuery:

```
$('.popup-content').on('click', function(){
    // Check if already open, early exit
    if ($(this).hasClass('show')) return;
    // Close them all
    $('.popup-content').removeClass('show')
    // Open the one being clicked
    $(this).addClass('show');
})
```

Another option is to use a wildcard selector

```js
$('[class^="popup"]').on('click', function(){
    // Check if already open, early exit
    if ($(this).hasClass('show')) return;
    // Close them all
    $('[class^="popup"]').removeClass('show');
    // Open the one being clicked
    $(this).addClass('show');
})
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.show p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup-content-1">
  1
<p>hidden content 1</p>
</div>
<div class="popup-content">
  2
<p>hidden content 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using selector attribute *(starts with)* you can select all popups, and based on popup class name, hide or show its content. This way you can add as many popups as you wish.

```
<button class="popup-1">1</button>
<span class="content-popup-1">First</span>

$("[class^=popup]").click(function() {
    $(".content-" + this.className).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/e9qep53w/

More about query selectors here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/